# What's the ideal pot size for seedlings that will be transplanted outdoors as soon as possible?

Tags: plant-care, planting, seedlings, transplanting, raised-beds

I was wondering what is the ideal pot size for seedlings like tomatoes, peppers and eggplants, that will be transplanted to an outdoors raised bed as soon as possible (is that when they have 2 sets of real leaves?).

Comment: Is it due to temperature indoors? Or easy caring that you want to plant them first in a pot?

Comment: It's because if I want to start early I have to put them indoors at night, until the night temperature is a bit higher, so I need to be able to move them around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just wondering if you're in the southern hemisphere that you're sowing and growing on these seedlings at this time of year...

Use small pots, not bigger than 9cm, to transplant your seedlings when they have at least one set of true leaves; grow the seedlings on into small plants with several sets of leaves, or until the roots have filled the pots, and gradually harden them off to acclimatize to outdoors, then plant out when outdoor temperatures are suitable.

Comment: Yes, im in south america.